# Пунктуация. БСП

Tags: пунктуация

Волков бояться, - значит, в лес не ходить.
В этом предложении так будут расставлены знаки препинания, если перед нами БСП со значением условия, между частями которого вставлено вводное слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**БСП и вводное слово — не лучшее оформление для этого предложения**. По Розенталю для этой фразы можно предложить **следующие варианты:**

1) Волков бояться — значит в лес не ходить. Простое предложение, ЗНАЧИТ — связка.

2) **Волков бояться —  в лес не ходить**. Бессоюзное предложение. Слово *значит* отсутствует.

3) Если волков бояться, значит, в лес не ходить. Сложноподчиненное предложение, ЗНАЧИТ — вводное слово в роли второй части союза ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ

Но в справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" приводится пример "БСП и вводное слово": **Послал он мне крест — значит, меня он любит (И. Тургенев).** Сравнить:  Если послал он мне крест, значит, меня он любит.  Тогда приведенное предложение будет выглядеть следующим образом: **Волков бояться — значит, в лес не ходить.**

[Розенталь. § 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)

12) Слово значит, если оно синонимично словам **следовательно, стало быть**, является **вводным** и выделяется запятыми: Солнечные пятна были на полу, потом перешли на прилавок, на стену и совсем исчезли; значит, солнце уже склонилось за полдень (Ч.); Родятся люди, женятся, умирают; значит, так нужно, значит, хорошо (Остр.); Так, значит, вы сегодня не можете прийти?; Сообщение срочное, а значит, важное.

Если слово значит близко по смыслу к слову **означает**, то пунктуация зависит от места, занимаемого им в предложении:

а) в положении между подлежащим и сказуемым слово значит служит средством связи главных членов предложения, перед ним ставится тире, а после него не ставится никакого знака: **Бороться — значит победить;**

б) в других случаях значит никакими знаками препинания не выделяется: Человек **значит** неизмеримо больше, чем принято думать о нём (М. Г.);

Если слово значит находится между придаточной и главной частями **сложноподчиненного** предложения и играет роль **структурного элемента** предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми: **Если** наступит весна, **значит**, будет тепло;

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пояснение!

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, многое зависит от понимания смысла этой нестандартной фразы.
"Волков бояться означает в лес не ходить"?
"Волков бояться, следовательно в лес не ходить"?
На мой взгляд, ни то ни другое. Скорее здесь гипотетическое условие "Если волков бояться, то придется в лес не ходить".

Вариант "Волков бояться — значит в лес не ходить" я бы отбросил. По Розенталю, такая структура подходит, если слово *значит* близко по смыслу к слову *означает*, а это не наш случай.

Вариант без тире типа "Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился" здесь тоже не подходит. Здесь слово *значит* близко по смыслу к слову *следовательно*. Тоже не наш случай.

Остается одно:

**Волков бояться — значит, в лес не ходить.**

Здесь *значит* - вводное слово, стоит просто для связки слов, обозначает продолжения речи (По Розенталю, это слова "указывающие на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения").

[Розенталь. § 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)